# Can't include php file from parent directory

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two side-menus on my Wordpress site that I have saved as php files. I am able to call these into my `page.php` file with the the following line of PHP `<?php include("mobile-menu.php"); ?>`

For some reason, I am unable to do the same in another of my page templates in a sub-folder. My template structure is fairly simple, in my main theme folder I have `header.php`, `footer.php`, `mobile-menu.php` etc. Then in a sub folder called "page-templates", I have another template called `full-page.php`. This is the template in which I am having trouble calling `mobile-menu.php` with the include function.

I have tried the following:

`<?php include("../mobile-menu.php"); ?>`

`<?php include(__DIR__."../mobile-menu.php"); ?>`

Comment: `<?php include( __DIR__ . "/../mobile-menu.php"); ?>`

Comment: it may be same but have u tried `<?php include '../mobile-menu.php'; ?>`

Comment: Maxim, thankyou this worked, I'd made a silly mistake and ommited the spaces between the `.`

Comment: Vikrant, thanks for the suggestion but I couldn't get this to work, I think it needs the brackets.